# JavaFX Modular set up with Apache NetBeans 12.3

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

So I've been following the [getting started with javaFX tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) to try and set up a modular FX project on apache netbeans, but I can't seem to figure out how to add the FXML files and CSS files. I managed to create a separate javaFX project that is non-modular with FXML and CSS files:
[non-modular ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHMYc.png)

I did this by right clicking the project and creating a 'new empty FXML' file. However, I don't see this same prompt when clicking on my modular project. basically for my modular project what I did was right click org.openjfx(the name of the package the tutorial made me make)-->new-->other, from here I tried to look for a JavaFX category (followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdTc_ZIGlMg&t=258s) youtube tutorial) but couldn't find it.

Would be really grateful for anybody who knows how to add FXML and CSS files to a modular project in netbeans! Thankyou

also here is the error code I receive when running the main class without configuring FXML or CSS files

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module format not recognized: C:\java projects\javafx-sdk-16\lib\src.zip
C:\Users\themo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\themo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:40: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

EDIT: There was a really helpful answer on how to build a modular project using Maven but I'm still open to anyone who has a response about building it directly from the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to follow the tutorial from [getting started with JavaFX tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/). I would suggest using `JavaFX and Netbeans: Modular with Maven`. Once you have created a project, right-click on the package you want to put the `Controller` into. Select `New` -> `Other` -> `JavaFX` -> `Empty FXML`. Name the `FXML` file. Hit `Next`. Select `Use Java Controller`. Hit `Next`. Select `Use Cascading Style Sheets`. That should do it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's working now :) Modular with Maven is much easier to use haha

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project,click Properties Then run and add this to VM option :

```
    --module-path "C:\path to java fx sdk\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Comment: I just added this to my VM options but the error code remains the same :(